# Repackage ubuntu after modifications

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was wondering if there is a way to take an Ubuntu ISO. Install it in a VM and install some tools and appilcations of choice and then repackage it (Back to ISO).

Given the new ISO. The user will go through the regular ubuntu installations; however, they will now have the newly added items at first start up.

If the above is not possible, how close to this concept can I get.

Comment: Its possible but even with Linux you would have driver problems depending on the virtual machine software your using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few options available.

There is a page on the Ubuntu Documentation website detailing [LiveCD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).

The [Ubuntu Mini Remix](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/) is also available for customization.

Fedora calls customized versions of the installation Spins.